# Why exactly does `std::shared_ptr` get copied when passed to a `std::thread` as an argument?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, stdthread

I'd like to verify my understanding of how `std::thread` makes a copy of a `shared_ptr` when it is passed one as an argument.

Assume the following code (C++ 17):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>


void const_reference(const std::shared_ptr<int>& data_ptr)
{
  std::cout << "value: " << *data_ptr << std::endl;
  std::cout << "shared_ptr address: " << &data_ptr << std::endl;
  std::cout << "data address: " << data_ptr.get() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Use count: " << data_ptr.use_count() << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<int> data_ptr = std::make_shared<int>(42);

  const_reference(data_ptr); // Use count stays 1 as expected - no copy is made.
  /*
   * value: 42
   * shared_ptr address: 0x7ff7ba1b9418
   * data address: 0x6000031a91b8
   * Use count: 1 
   */

  std::thread worker {const_reference, data_ptr}; // Use count is 2 - a copy is made.
  /*
   * value: 42
   * shared_ptr address: 0x6000031a91d0
   * data address: 0x6000031a91b8
   * Use count: 2
   */

  worker.join();

  return 0;
}
```

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) the constructor is as follows:

```cpp
template< class Function, class... Args > 
explicit thread( Function&& f, Args&&... args );
// The new thread of execution starts executing

INVOKE(decay-copy(std::forward<Function>(f)),
       decay-copy(std::forward<Args>(args))...).
```

If I understand correctly, a copy of the args is already made (using `decay-copy`) before it is passed to `f`, so the `x` in `const_reference(x)` is a copy of the `shared_ptr` (and of course that can be then taken as a `const&`). Is this correct? I'd very much appreciate it if someone with a deep understanding could write clear explanation.

A side note: clang-tidy recommends taking a const reference to a `shared_ptr` if it is only used as a const reference, but I'd argue that it is clearer to make it explicit a copy is made when it is used in this way.

Comment: to avoid copy you should use std::ref(data_ptr)

Comment: [`decay-copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/standard_library/decay-copy) is the one actually requiring a copy. It takes a forwarding reference to `T` and returns `decay_t<T>`, non-referenced non-qualified version of `T`.

Comment: what copy is confusing you? You already know that a copy is made to pass it to the constructor, but what other copy do you refer to?

Comment: or... what other output did you expect?

Comment: oh I think now I understand your quesiton. Your understanding is correct, not much more to say about it

Comment: This question was closed as duplicate, but I don't think any of the duplicates explains in detail how it actually works under the hood. Thanks at least for confirming my high level understanding :)

Comment: the question you did ask is "Is this correct?" if you wanted to ask about something "under the hood" you should be more specific